# Check number include other number in ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers

How to check number include other number in ruby?

example :

```
number1 = 1321
number2 = 2
```

how to check number1 contains number2?

```
1321 contains 2 is true
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "[a] number include[d] [in] [an]other number". Do you mean prime factorization (in which case your expected example is wrong)? Or any other decomposition?

Comment: Please do not create duplicate questions. If your first wasn't clear then edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this to return true or false

```
number1.to_s.include?(number2.to_s)
```

Comment: how scan string just for match value?

example :

"23" include "2" is true

"22" include "2" is false (get false because value is "22" not "2")

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you why "23" include "2" is true and  "22" include "2" is false ?

Comment: 23 have containt 2 and 3 thats its true, whereas 22 have 2 and 2 it's not allowed thats is false. if 232 have 2, 3 and 2 it's because have 3 between 2

Answer (score 0):

This is a *string* question, not a number question. Numbers don't contain other numbers. You need to convert both to strings:

```
s1 = 1321.to_s # => "1321"
s2 = 2.to_s # => "2"
```

Then, just use `[]`:

```
s1[s2] # => "2"
```

This will return the indexed value if it was found, or `nil`:

```
s1["9"] # => nil
```

Comment: how to get result true or false?

Comment: You don't need  true or false. You already have a truthy/falsy value. You can simply say `if s1[s2]`.

Comment: sholeh, The method [String#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) has several forms, as you can see from the docs.  meagar used the last of those forms here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is converting numbers to string and check if the sub-string exists in main string using [String#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
number1 = 1321
number2 = 2

sn1 = number1.to_s
# => "1321"
sn2 = number2.to_s
# => "2"

"#{sn1} contains #{sn2} is #{sn1.include?(sn2)}"
# => "1321 contains 2 is true"
```

False case example:

```
number1 = 1321
number2 = 9

sn1 = number1.to_s
# => "1321"
sn2 = number2.to_s
# => "9"

"#{sn1} contains #{sn2} is #{sn1.include?(sn2)}"
# => "1321 contains 9 is false"
```

Answer (score 0):

@meagar, it *can* be viewed as a number question (sort of):

```
def number_in_number?(outer, inner)
  test = 10**((inner < 2) ? 1 : Math.log10(inner).ceil.to_i)
  while outer >= inner
    return true if ((outer - inner) % test).zero?
    outer /= 10
  end
  false
end

number_in_number?(1321, 2)         #=> true 
number_in_number?(1321, 32)        #=> true 
number_in_number?(1321, 4)         #=> false
number_in_number?(1321, 1321)      #=> true 
number_in_number?(1321, 13211)     #=> false  
number_in_number?(543681321, 4368) #=> true 
number_in_number?(543681321, 4367) #=> false
```